# Change button to red

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In form view of sale order, I have a button

```
<button name="action_confirm" states="sent" string="Confirm Sale" class="btn-primary" type="object" context="{'show_sale': True}"/>
```

and it's showing in blue color. if I change to oe_highlight nothing changes or any other class. How can I change this button to RED color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

class="btn-danger"

Comment: then remove class and use this > style="background-color:red"